# Generate table rows in the loop with Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, append, createelement

I don't get how to generate rows after some condition in the loop. A code below tries to make calendar table, but I can't figure out why it shows only last row with condition. Please help to fix it

```js
let start = document.querySelector('div');
let table = document.createElement('table');
let row = document.createElement('tr');
let date = new Date(2015,5);

while (date.getMonth() == 5){
  let td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerHTML= date.getDate();
  row.appendChild(td);

  if ( date.getDay()%6 == 0){
    table.appendChild(row) //want that it add new row after each 7 days
    console.log(table)
    row.innerHTML = '';
  }

  date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1) ;   
}

table.appendChild(row)
start.appendChild(table)
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: please provide the full HTML code so we can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick,

```js
let start = document.querySelector('div');
let table = document.createElement('table');
let row = document.createElement('tr');
let date = new Date(2015,5);

while (date.getMonth() == 5){
  let td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerHTML= date.getDate();
  row.appendChild(td);

  if ( (date.getDay()%7) == 0){
    table.appendChild(row) //want that it add new row after each 7 days
    row = document.createElement('tr');
  }

  date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1) ;   
}

table.appendChild(row)
start.appendChild(table)
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

I just made two changes,

- On line #12, modified the if condition,
  `if (date.getDay()%6 == 0)` => `if (date.getDay()%7 == 0)`
  the former would be true for both 0(Sunday) and 6(Saturday), causing incorrect number of rows. The latter correctly breaks the row by doing modulo 7 as there are 7 days in a week
- On line #15, I replaced,
  `row.innerHTML = '';` => `row = document.createElement('tr');`
  the former just mutates the reference of the row already added to the table, and thus effectively deletes the cells in the row. With the latter you are creating a new row object and adding cells to it.

Comment: Described clearly. But why, if we console.log 'table' in the loop we get each time a completed one, but not a snapshot of its creation step?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each time `row.innerHTML = '';` get executed you empty the row you build.
What you should do is create a new row instead, like so: `row = document.createElement('tr');`
Also there is 7 days in the week so you should create new row every 7 days not 6 `( date.getDay()%7 == 0)`

Here is the code after the fix:

```js
let start = document.querySelector("body > div");
let table = document.createElement('table');
let row = document.createElement('tr');
let date = new Date(2015,5,1);

while (date.getMonth()===5){
  let td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerHTML= date.getDate();
  row.appendChild(td);        
  if (date.getDay()%7 === 0){
    table.appendChild(row); //want that it add new row after each 7 days
    row = document.createElement('tr');// we create new row istead of cleating the previous one
  }
  date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1);   
}
table.appendChild(row);
start.appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```